# spring: package does not exist

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am a beginner of Java and Spring framework. I've test a simple controller which use spring annotation.

I am doing this using `notepad` and I have already set jar files to classpath ( jar files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFjSW.jpg )

But when i tried to compile the programs i have get the error ( detail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFvxG.jpg ) like

1. error: `package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist`
2. error: `package org.springframework.ui does not exist`
3. error: `package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not
   exist`

How can i fix this problem?
Thanks~

Comment: where you have been placed your .jar files ?

Comment: Please post the error message and JAR list as text instead of images.

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: Please provide console output as code in the post instead of an image. From your screenshot I cannot see that your jar files are on the classpath.

Comment: Why notepad and javac? No pain, no gain? They even have their own version of [eclipse](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) to make development more productive.

Comment: OK, i will try to use/learn STS and maven, thanks all~

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile likes this,

```
javac -cp .;your_library_path/spring-aop-4.0.jar;your_library_path/spring-aspects-4.0.jar controller.java
```

You need to declare all of your external libraries separate with `;`but personally I recommend you should try to use some java IDEs likes eclipse, netbeans,etc.